# load balancer for web page

Tags: load-balancing

Which load balancer is the best for fail over server. If first server is down then ip is changed to second one. If first goes back ip for domain is changed back to first server.

For WIN os, or some provider who has this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some experience with Gogrid and F5 load balancer, for stateless applications this works fine.  If your application needs to maintain the session state across all servers you will need to do some custom programming (session state in sql server, ...)

Answer (score 1):

> Which load balancer is the best for fail over server

You need to go a very long way to get a better solution than Round-Robin DNS. You certainly won't find a cheaper solution. Note that you do need unique ip addresses for each node exposed at the point where the failover is applied (usually on the client)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to balance the server with 1 internet line you can look at Kemp Technologies (server load balancers)

If you are planning to have multiple internet lines you can look at Fiberlogic Optiqroute, their units can have from 2-10 WAN ports (to connect different lines) and the unit will balance servers connected in the LAN. They can do Round Robin or best possible line.